# Ubuntu boot USB has recursive infinite file called "Ubuntu" is that normal?

Tags: boot, usb

[image]

I installed an Ubuntu 20.04 ISO on my desktop and I made an Ubuntu boot in my USB and I got this, is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

That ubuntu file is a link, and was added years ago to the ISO.  Unfortunately, that link killed the possibility of just making a boot media on a FAT32 device, since the FAT32 filesystem does not support links.  It might be used by something in the preseed arena, but it can just be ignored.

---

It's normal and nothing to worry about.